# Is this a well defined integral : $ \mathrm{V}(x):=\int_0^{\infty}\left\|e^{s A} x\right\|^2 \mathrm{ds}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^m $

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I want to ask whether the following integral is well-defined meaning it gives us finite values at all points:
$$
\mathrm{V}(x):=\int_0^{\infty}\left\|e^{s A} x\right\|^2 \mathrm{ds}, \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^m
$$

In the case where the eigenvalues of $A$ have strictly negative real parts, this is actually a Lyapunov function for the linear flow of $e^{tA}$.

Comment: I assume $A$ symmetric. Let us write $B=-A$ in order that $B$ is positive definite. This integral, written under the form $X=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-Bt}(xx^T)e^{-Bt}dt$ is a solution to a Sylvester equation $UX+XU=V$

Comment: Maybe I don't really get what you are asking but if you take $A=I$ where $I$ is the identity on $\mathbb{R^m}$, then $V(x)$ is finite if and only if $x  = 0$.

Comment: Your integral converges only if the eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real part.

Comment: @lcv , hi, may i ask why we need negative real parts?